# Trouble connecting to API with Dart

Tags: flutter, rest, dart

I have the code I think I need to connect to a REST API but I get this error:

[image]

Here is the code I am using:

```
var url =
        Uri.parse('https://realty-mole-property-api.p.rapidapi.com/properties');//+ parameters);
    var response = await client.get(
      url,
      headers: {
        'X-RapidAPI-Key': '51ced1b32emsh509f82e1d58ae16p1ad6e6jsn75d75166a8b4',
        'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'realty-mole-property-api.p.rapidapi.com'
      },
    );
```

The API documentation is found here: https://rapidapi.com/realtymole/api/realty-mole-property-api

I have used the code snippet example for the C# code.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could this be a firewall issue?  Are you running on a real device or an emulator using your company's network? What happens if you just try opening https://realty-mole-property-api.p.rapidapi.com/properties in a browser on the phone or emulator you are testing on?

Comment: I'm using an emulator but I work from home so there is no company network. I don't even think we use a VPN. When I put the URL into a browser I get this message:  {"message":"Invalid API key. Go to https:\/\/docs.rapidapi.com\/docs\/keys for more info."}

Comment: What happens when you enter that URL in the browser inside the emulator? BTW - the above code works fine in DartPad - you can try it there too.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. I had a VPN running that I was not aware of. Turned it off and now I can access the API but now I have other issues.
Thanks all for your help